# Reverse a hexadecimal number in bash

Tags: command-line, numeric-data, hex

Is there a simple command to reverse an hexadecimal number?

For example, given the hexadecimal number:

```
030201
```

The output should be:

```
010203
```

Using the `rev` command, I get the following:

```
102030
```

**Update**

```
$ bash --version | head -n1
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ xxd -version
xxd V1.10 27oct98 by Juergen Weigert
$ rev --version
rev from util-linux 2.20.1
```

Comment: Please don't add the answer to your question.

Comment: @cat I added the answer because the one that worked for me, is at the comments of the selected answer. But I'm ok removing it.

Comment: You could add it as an answer by clicking the "Answer this question" button below the answer box (self-answers are encouraged), and you should, just don't put it in the question.

Comment: The C programmer in me wants to say "010203" is an octal number, not a hex number (0x10203)

Comment: @infixed You are not wrong, but I wanted an answer that treats `010203` as an hexadecimal, even though I do not use  `0x`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [convert it to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681385/96588), [reverse the bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11461628/96588), optionally [remove trailing newlines `rev` <2.24](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321860/reverse-a-hexadecimal-number-in-bash/321862?noredirect=1#comment565812_321862), and convert it back:

```
$ xxd -revert -plain <<< 030201 | LC_ALL=C rev | tr -d '\n' | xxd -plain
010203
```

Using

```
$ bash --version | head -n1
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
$ xxd -version
xxd V1.10 27oct98 by Juergen Weigert
$ rev --version
rev from util-linux 2.28.2
```

This does *not* work if the string contains `00` (the NUL byte), because `rev` will truncate the output at that point, or `0a` (newline), because `rev` reverses each *line* rather than the entire output.

Comment: I get `0102030a` instead of `010203`

Comment: @l0b0 and too me,get `0102030a`

Comment: @IñakiMurillo Strange. Did you run *exactly* the command above? If so, which `bash`/`xxd`/`rev` versions are you using?

Comment: @l0b0 I run it exactly. I updated the question with software versions

Comment: A `0a` at the end must mean that a newline was introduced at some point (`0x0a` is newline in ASCII).

Comment: @IñakiMurillo  in your `rev` version `2.20.1`; use this formate `xxd -revert -plain <<< '030201' | LC_ALL=C rev | tr -d '\n'| xxd -plain`

Comment: `rev` before version `2.24` have a new line bug . more info https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/d267fdb8540202f77efb28fdf5dddd9826626757

Comment: It does not work if the hex string contains the '00' NUL byte.

Answer (score 12):

With `fold` + `tac` + `tr` :

```
$ echo 030201|fold -w2|tac|tr -d "\n"
010203
```

- `fold` - split every 2 byte
- `tac` - reverse cat
- `tr` - remove newlines

Answer (score 11):

If your system has a `rev` command.

```
hex=030201
new_hex=$(printf %s "$hex" | dd conv=swab 2> /dev/null | rev)
```

If it has a `tac` or `tail -r` command:

```
new_hex=$(echo "$hex" | fold -w 2 | tac | paste -sd '\0' -)
```

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
new_hex=${(j[])${(s[]Oa)${hex//(#b)(?)(?)/$match[2]$match[1]}}}
```

(like in the `dd` approach: swap pairs of characters, split into list of individual characters (`s[]`), reverse the order (`Oa`) and join (`j[]`)).

Or:

```
printf -v new_hex '%2$s%1$s' ${(s[]Oa)hex}
```

POSIXly:

```
new_hex=$(
  awk '
    BEGIN {
      hex = ARGV[1]; l = length(hex)
      for (i = 1; i < l; i += 2)
        new_hex = substr(hex, i, 2) new_hex
      print new_hex
    }' "$hex"
)
```

Or

```
new_hex=$(echo "$hex" |
  sed -e 'G;:1' -e 's/\(..\)\(.*\n\)/\2\1/;t1' -e 's/.//')
```

With `perl`:

```
new_hex=$(perl -le 'print reverse(shift =~ /../g)' -- "$hex")
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `perl -F'(..)' -lane 'print reverse(@F)'` :)

Comment: @Sundeep, nice. I didn't know one could use `-F` like that. (I can see it described in the `split()` manual now).

Comment: as far as I know, `-F` is basically splitting on `$_`.. apart from using regex like `-F'/"\K\|(?=")/'` one can specify number of splits as well... like `-F'/:/,$_,2'` ... use `()` if separator has to be captured as well

Comment: Instead of using paste you could use `tr -d '\n'`

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -nE 'say reverse /(..)/g'
```

This reverts each hexadecimal line:

- `/(..)/g` buils a list with the captured matches

Answer (score 4):

(for the sake of completeness)

```
$ echo 030201 | grep -o .. | tac | paste -sd '' -
010203
```

Comment: *This* works if the '00' NUL byte is in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ipor Sircer's answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321867/337458 I would recommend this in your `~/.bashrc` to have a nice command that you simply can call:

```
function hex_inverse() {
    echo ${1} | fold -w2 | tac | tr -d "\n" ; echo "" 
}
```

```
$> hex_inverse 030201

010203
```